# Apache rewrite rules for Slim (PHP) RESTful API

Tags: apache, .htaccess, rest, mod-rewrite, slim

I'm having some trouble configuring my RESTful API (using Slim PHP and Eloquent ORM) to rewrite URL's correctly.

My project directory structure goes like this:

```
wwwroot/
    myproject/
        api/ (maintained in its own Git repo)
            app/
                data/
                lib/
                models/
                routes/
                app.php (where Slim is instantiated and used)
                config.php (holds database settings, etc.)
            public/
                .htaccess (#1)
                index.php (includes ../app/app.php)
            vendor/
            .htaccess (#2, this be empty yo)
        ngapp/ (future Angular.js app)
        webapp/ (future standard web app)
```

`.htaccess` (#1) contains the standard rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

This makes the API reachable via `http://localhost/myproject/api/public/<insertAnySlimRouteHere>`. However, I want to reach the API via an URL such as this: `http://localhost/myproject/api/<insertAnySlimRouteHere>`. How do I do this?

(Feel free to comment on my overall project structure too. I'm trying to learn how to develop a RESTful API in a language I seldom use nowadays since I'm employed as a .NET/JS developer, using two frameworks I've never dabbled with before and making it (the API) suitable for several clients, both on web and on mobile devices. Learning is fun, whenever there is time.)

## Update

I followed smcjones' suggestion and added the following to my `httpd-vhosts.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Alias "/lampjavel/api" "C:/Users/Viktor/Dev/htdocs/lampjavel-api/public"
    <Directory "C:/Users/Viktor/Dev/htdocs/lampjavel-api">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I also deleted my `.htaccess` #2 and my `.htaccess` #1 (in `public/`) looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

However, the first part of the Slim route gets thrown away. When I access `.../api` in browser I get the `/` route, which is correct. But when I request `.../api/images` I still get the `/` route. If I delve deeper to `.../api/images/images` I get my desired route, `/images`.

In my `app.php`:

```
$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
    echo '/';
});

$app->get('/images', function () use ($app) {
    echo '/images';
});
```

Any idea why the first part of the route gets ignored?

Comment: I wanted to split this point off from my answer, but I still wanted to throw it out there: If you are creating a RESTful API, it can be in any language (Java, .NET, PHP, etc.), so long as the output is the correct protocol. So if you're looking to develop for speed, why not stick with what you know and do .NET w/ IIS? You can always create an API client for PHP.

Comment: I am aware. I'm as fluent in PHP as in C#, but I like PHP better, it's cleaner and cheaper. And some day I would like to work professionally with PHP so I'd like some experience. Java is my native language and JavaScript is what I mostly do at work since everybody else is either too scripty with it (horrible code) or thinks it's more and less the client-side version of C# (which can lead to horrible bugs). And this API is also the starting point of me learning maybe some fun JS libs and Android development, but then I have to have an API I can communicate with. And I'm bad at server confing!

Comment: You have an error in your `<Directory>` tag. You will probably want to just use the alias, aka `"/lampjavel/api"` for simplicity's sake.

Comment: Still the same problem though, but when I access `http://localhost/lampjavel/api/index.php/images` I get routed correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking to accomplish in its stated form would be unwieldy and insecure.

**Unwieldy**, because you are trying to call child folders from the parent. This could lead to several unforeseen issues. For example:

- You need to disallow the folders which are in your project structure from being called using your `mod_rewrite`. Otherwise, your server will try to serve you a Slim route instead of, say, `app`. While you could add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`, that would miss the point, because then your `app` route wouldn't work on Slim.
- For this reason you will also never be able to have a Slim route named `app`. While you most likely have no intention of having a Slim route named `app`, it is better to give your application the flexibility.
- On a similar note, if you ever decided you needed another folder (let's say, `docs`, or `test` for unit testing), you would either need to bury it under another folder, like `app` or `public` (where, at least to me, they don't seem like they fit), or you will need to change your `mod_rewrite`. You will also need to look out for naming conflicts all over again. In this sense, unless you are 100% sure you are not going to modify your structure, you're adding more pain for yourself than would be necessary.

**Insecure**, because your web path is currently set to show a big portion of your directory structure. While this seems to me like a development server, where it may not matter, I think it's good practice to get your paths in order on your development server first.

Currently, if you navigate to `http://localhost/myproject/api/app/data`, does it throw a 404? Would someone be able to guess your structure? Are there any pages that you would not want someone to find outside of your root? While PHP will not present any of these files, someone would easily be able to overload your system by calling files. Also, if a file throws an error when called alone, you may be giving up more information about your path.

Again, I realize that you are probably just testing this out, but if it is going into a live environment at some point, these are issues you will need to deal with. I have given myself a lot less grief after I started trying to make my development server emulate my live server as much as possible.

**My Proposed Solution**

`.htaccess` is really not the ideal place to conduct these sorts of operations. Instead, you should be looking at Apache's configuration files. As @guillermoandrae stated, what it sounds like you're really looking to do is have a different `DocumentRoot`.

If you can access Apache's configuration you can create a [`VirtualHost`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html) which points directly to the `public` directory.

Example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Alias "/api" /wwwroot/myproject/api/public
    <Directory "/api">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine on
            #Rewrite Rules from .htaccess here
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

You can add more `Directory` tags here and create a secure application with aliases to folders you need to reach.

**A (long) note about your project structure**

I already mentioned that your project structure ***may*** have to change at some point. Overall I would mention that your project structure looks good. PHP is an overly forgiving language, which can be bad, but with your background means you'll be doing just fine. However, one thing I would suggest is that you split off your `api` folder into its own project. The reason I recommend this is because it is currently pretty tightly woven with your one application. You mentioned you want it to work with multiple applications. Well, the beauty of an API is that it works so long as you can access the URI. So long as you are creating a RESTful API (or even a JSon-based API), any language can parse your API regardless of where it is.

Currently, if you created a new project, say `mysecondproject`, you would have two identical URL's:

`http://localhost/myproject/api/public/foo` and `http://localhost/mysecondproject/api/public/foo` would both go to the same place. Unless you did not update the project in one place, in which case you would find inconsistencies.

Ultimately I would suspect that unless you are looking to have mirrors, you probably want your API to exist in one location on the internet. This gives you better control over, well, everything.

### EDIT

Based on your questions below, your directory is being rerouted due to your mod_rewrite code. Without knowing what you're using right now for rewrites, I will suggest you add this single line and see how it works (after `...%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

### EDIT #2

Your htaccess code is currently pushing everything that is not a directory or a file off of your main directory to Slim. So chances are good the error is in your Slim routes and not your Apache access. Do you have a route that looks something like this?

```
$app->get('/images/:route', function ($route) {

    //execute code
};
```

If you do not, then try to figure out what route is being implemented. You can probably use some of Slim's built in logging capabilities if it is hard to locate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm at work now so I can't play with your suggested solution. I made a query to my "web space provider" and I cannot change the Apache conf unfortunately. That was my initial understanding also and the reason for trying to solve it using `.htaccess` files. They say that they have support for "htaccess" and "mod_rewrite", but that's it. If virtual hosts is the right way to go, maybe I should change my provider.

Comment: Although I have the option to specify "web aliases" in my provider's UI, that is subdomains. I.e., http://phpinfo.vikto.re should point to http://vikto.re/bienvenue/phpinfo.php, see pic: http://i.imgur.com/C0rTUGi.png

Comment: hostgator.com maybe? How to know if you can conf Apache with a specific provider?

Comment: I would recommend skipping this step and just creating a different project if you can. That may not be possible though if you have price constraints on hostgator.com. In that case, looks like you can file a support ticket here: http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/apache-htaccess/httpd-configuration-httpd-conf

Comment: I'm sorry, I was unclear. I have a Swedish host (one.com) for which a pay about a pizza a year for space, PHP and MySQL. I was in contact with their help desk and they told me that they did not support configuring Apache such as you suggested. Only htaccess and mod_rewrite, quoting them. So I would have to find a new host if I decide to go with the proposed solution and maybe so I should. I can however edit the Apache config on my local dev environment, but apparently I can never take it further with my current host.

Comment: A VPS hosting solution may be affordable though. But if we skip the future prod environment and focus on Your Proposed Solution. I kept the default `public/.htaccess` in place and added your `<VirtualHost>` directives to my `httpd-vhosts.conf`, changed the paths (for `Alias` and `<Directory>`) and deleted the `<IfModule>`.

Comment: It works now to some extent, but the "level" is f'ed up. 

`http://localhost/myproject/api` => `http://localhost/myproject/api` = correct
`http://localhost/myproject/api/route` => `http://localhost/myproject/api` = incorrect
`http://localhost/myproject/api/whatever/route` => `http://localhost/myproject/api/route` = incorrect

My first route parameter seems to get ignored for some reason? Should be really simple...

Comment: Also, re: your nice priced web host, it could be worth paying for a new website at one.com just for your API. Probably cheaper than a new host.

Comment: I will look into it, but I think it would be best to use a virtual server for all future websites and whatnot. I found hosting solutions for $10-20 a month which gave me full root access and that should take care of the Apache problem. Right now I think I'm using a shared server.

Comment: Regarding my actual question, I'm still just using the rewrites provided by Slim, extended with your `VirtualHost` config. See my repository for a snapshot: https://github.com/vikekh/lampjavel-api (this is the repo for the API only).

Comment: Yes you're using a shared server right now. A VPS is the ideal way to go (AWS has a good micro instance which offers a year free and you can always upgrade, and I am a big fan of DigitalOcean for its easy of use). The rewrites will help you but over time a VPS will allow you the most flexibility. There is also a learning curve on some of them (AWS more than DigitalOcean) so be aware of that.

Comment: I updated my question yesterday, since I cannot get the config to play nice.

Comment: Yes, I have a Slim route that looks like that. I currently use `Alias "/lampjavel/api" "C:/Users/Viktor/Dev/htdocs/lampjavel-api/public/index.php"` in my Apache config to make it work. Do you happen to know why this works?

Comment: My best guess is that there's something wrong with your mod rewrite. Maybe the module is missing? http://sevennet.org/2015/01/04/answer-how-to-i-test-if-mod_rewrite-is-enabled-programming-solution-development/

Comment: Hm, no, it's there, according to `phpinfo()`. :/

Comment: I can't really tell you... Without digging in myself I have absolutely no way of figuring out why or how that would happen. But, I'd say count your lucky stars it works and try with your VPS when you have a chance.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the `DocumentRoot` for your app is actually `wwwroot/myproject/api` and you want it to be `wwwroot/myproject/api/public`. You could just set the `DocumentRoot` directive, or just do this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /public/index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Neither seems to work correctly though. With the `RewriteRule` the first Slim parameter was always ignored so I had to write `http://localhost/myproject/api/<whatever>/<insertAnySlimRouteHere>`?

Comment: Can you set `DocumentRoot` from `.htaccess`? I've been trying at this all day and I cannot get it working correctly. Are you sure that your config is correct? If I read your rules you rewrite all incoming requests to `public/index.php` which is then picked up by my initial `.htaccess` file? What do the flags do? Should we use `RewriteBase`. The documentation on this matter is really sparse and unclear...

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your .htaccess #2 (in api/) :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [L]
```